# Sobrecarga de operadores en C ++

Tags: c++, sobrecarga-de-operadores

```
#define TAMSEC 59
#define TAMMIN 59
#define TAMHOURS 23

using namespace std;

class Time{
private:
int hours,
    minutes,
    seconds;
public:
Time(int hours = 0, int minutes = 0, int seconds = 0);
/**Sobre carga operador <<**/
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Time &obj);
/**Sobrecarga operador (Pre incremento ++)**/
Time& operator ++();
/**Sobrecarga operador (Pos incremento ++)**/
Time operator ++(int);
 };

 /**Sobrecarga operador (Pre incremento ++)**/
Time& Time::operator ++(){
seconds ++;
if(seconds > TAMSEC){
    minutes ++;
    seconds = 0;
    if(minutes > TAMMIN){
        minutes = 0;
        hours ++;
        if(hours > TAMHOURS)
            hours = 0;
    }
}
return *this;
}
/**Sobrecarga operador (Pos incremento ++)**/
Time Time::operator++(int){
Time aux = Time(*this);
seconds ++;
if(seconds > TAMSEC){
    minutes ++;
    seconds = 0;
    if(minutes > TAMMIN){
        minutes = 0;
        hours ++;
        if(hours > TAMHOURS)
            hours = 0;
    }
  }
  return aux;
  }
```

Estaba desarrollando la sobrecarga de operadores del pos y pre incremento de mi clase Time, mi duda radica cuando hago el pos incremento, al principio quería devolver la referencia de mi objeto (*aux) que creé dentro de la función miembro antes de incrementar sus atributos, pero ésta no me deja, a si que tuve que devolver el objeto en si. ¿Por que no puedo devolver la referencia de mi objeto aux?

```
   Time& Time::operator++(int){
   Time aux = Time(*this);
   seconds ++;
   if(seconds > TAMSEC){
      minutes ++;
      seconds = 0;
      if(minutes > TAMMIN){
        minutes = 0;
        hours ++;
        if(hours > TAMHOURS)
          hours = 0;
      }
   }
   return *aux;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int& func()
{
  int variable=5;
  return variable;
}
```

Analicemos la función anterior:

Se crea una variable local, se le asigna un valor y se devuelve una referencia a la misma. ¿El problema? Que al abandonar la función la variable se pierde, luego la referencia devuelta no es válida.

Este mismo concepto es aplicable a tu código. **Nunca** debes devolver una referencia a una variable local porque la vida de la referencia será mayor que la vida de la variable.

En tu ejemplo, sin embargo, si vale hacer `return *this;` porque, como sabes, `*this` apunta al objeto actual, el cual seguirá vivo después de salir de la función de post-incremento.

Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Sería parecido a:

```
T *p = new T;
T &r = *p;
delete p;
// Hacer uso de r.
```

Un variable local de una funcción es automaticamente eliminado cuando se termina la funcción.

Sugiero:

```
Time operator ++(int) { Time aux = *this; ++*this; return(aux); }
```

(en linea).  Evita repetición en el código fuente.  Por ser en linea, permita que el compilador elimie **aux** cuando el valor devuelto no se usa, y applicar mejor copy epsilon cuando el valor devuelto sí se usa.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47769/discussion-on-answer-by-waltk-sobrecarga-de-operadores-en-c).